# Pushing messages from server to client in windows application (HTTP only)

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, http

I have several clients connected to a server using TCP. Because of some problems with the TCP (or the IT policies) I want to change the protocol to TCP using either web service or web API

The problem is that the HTTP is a request from client to server, but not the other way around
[image]

I want to create this option where the server can push responses to the client

Server:
.NET windows application with TCP connections, hold few clients each client has a logic instance

Client:
.net windows application with TCP connection

Because of the server architecture I don't want to use ASP.NET or other application rely on IIS.

Does WCF can provide me with this solution?

Comment: You should look into WCF Callbacks: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=721, You may also be able to use Signal R but I am unsure.

Answer (score 0):

We use SignalR in one of our projects

[NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SignalR/)

[Video Tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Belgium-2013/25)

IIS is not necessary, you can self-host this service (as we just do)

Comment: I know web API. I didn't know that web API can push back messages